# Why the command of python is not executed in the terminal

Tags: error-handling, project, madlib

Hi Guys im trying to copy the code from the video even though i do everything as mentioned in the video but still error, can you please tell me where i made a mistake?[this is how she made it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llG5a.png). [image: this is my version with errors]

Answer (score 0):

Try using your terminal inside of vscode. Right click on the file you want to open and select "Open in integrated Terminal".

Comment: Thank you so much inside it works but when i open iterm or terminal it doesnt even react to the command of python

Comment: This is because your terminal is not in the right folder. You would have to navigate to where your project folder is located on your terminal. I would help there but I'm terrible at terminal commands, plus I don't know where your project is held.